# Why 'cv2.imshow()' function is not displaying my image properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Whenever I run my code every image is shown correctly except the one named 'FireRegion'. It is being displayed as transparent window or errored window. The countNonZero() function works fine though but the image is not being displayed. It works properly when I don't use the np.where() function and to use that after that I need to use the astype to convert image type to uint8 otherwise the compiler gives an error. I think its happening because of the bitwise_and() but its just a guess. Below is my code :

```
from playsound import playsound
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import time

if True:
    img = cv2.imread('WFire.jpg')
    Rule1 = img.copy()
    Rule2 = img.copy()
    Rule3 = img.copy()
    Rule4 = img.copy()
    Rule5 = img.copy()
    RE = img.copy()
    RE2 = img.copy()
    Ymean = img.copy()

    YCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    Y = YCrCb[:,:,0]
    Cr = YCrCb[:,:,1]
    Cb = YCrCb[:,:,2]

    Ym = int(np.mean(Y))
    Crm = int(np.mean(Cr))
    Cbm = int(np.mean(Cb))

    # h = img.shape[0]
    # w = img.shape[1]

    # for x in range(0,h) :
        # for y in range(0,w) :
            # RE[x,y] = 255 if Y[x,y] > Cb[x,y] else 0
            # RE2[x,y] = 255 if Cr[x,y] > Cb[x,y] else 0
            # Rule3[x,y] = 255 if abs(int(Cb[x,y])-int(Cr[x,y]))>=70 else 0
            # RE[x,y] = 255 if Y[x,y]>Ym or Cb[x,y]>Cbm or Cr[x,y]>Crm else 0  
            # RE2[x,y] = 255 if Cb[x,y]<=120 and Cr[x,y]>=150 else 0
            
    Ymean = np.where(True,Ym,0)       
       
    Rule1 = np.where(Y>Cb,255,0)
    Rule2 = np.where(Cr>Cb,255,0)
    Rule3 = np.where(abs(Cb-Cr)>=70,255,0)
    Rule4 = np.where((Y>Ym)|(Cb>Cbm)|(Cr>Crm),255,0) 
    Rule5 = np.where((Cb<=120) & (Cr>=150),255,0)
    
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(Rule1,Rule2)   
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(FireRegion,Rule3)   
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(FireRegion,Rule4)   
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(FireRegion,Rule5)
    # FireRegionGray = cv2.cvtColor(FireRegion.astype(np.float32),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
    NFP = cv2.countNonZero(FireRegion)
    print(NFP)
    # if NFP>2000 :
        # playsound('duck1.mp3')
    
    cv2.imshow("Y",Y)
    cv2.imshow("Cr",Cr)
    cv2.imshow("Cb",Cb)
    cv2.imshow("Original",img)
    cv2.imshow("Rule1",Rule1.astype(np.uint8))
    cv2.imshow("Rule2",Rule2.astype(np.uint8))
    cv2.imshow("Rule3",Rule3.astype(np.uint8))
    cv2.imshow("Rule4",Rule4.astype(np.uint8))
    cv2.imshow("Rule5",Rule5.astype(np.uint8))
    cv2.imshow("FireRegion",FireRegion.astype(np.uint8))

    
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    # if key ==27 :
        # break
```

Comment: what's the type of Rule1 to Rule5? Can you try pixrl-wise multiplication instead of bitwise_and?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    FR_1 = cv2.bitwise_and(Rule1,Rule2)   
    FR_2 = cv2.bitwise_and(FR_1,Rule3)   
    FR_3 = cv2.bitwise_and(FR_2,Rule4)   
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(FR_3,Rule5)
```

In place of:

```
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(Rule1,Rule2)   
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(FireRegion,Rule3)   
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(FireRegion,Rule4)   
    FireRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(FireRegion,Rule5)
```